# Is there a way to stop cruise control from processing during specific times?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

I'm trying to implement cruisecontrol.net with our ClearCase source control. There are specific times when the ClearCase repository is not available. (Scheduled backup times). Is there a way to tell cruisecontrol.net not to process during those blackout times?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be, for each [CCNet Build loop](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/index.html) to set a variable depending on the availability of ClearCase at the CC Server side.

One of the way of ensuring proper backup for ClearCase is to stop the albd (Atria Location Broker Service).
That triggers very fast error message as soon as you are stopping that daemon, for all sort of ClearCase commands, like a `cleartool lsview myView`.

I don't have a specific CCNet way of doing that, but at least you have a clear way of determining if ClearCase is stopped or not for backups.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the times when ClearCase is unavailable, the [cron trigger](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Cron_Trigger) should do the trick. You can combine it with another trigger using a [multi-trigger](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Multi_Trigger) clause with the `And` parameter.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  Since I do know the times when CC is unavailable, this will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a multi-trigger that contained a "Filter trigger" and an "interval trigger" together.  The filter trigger was used to define the blackout periods and the interval trigger was used in conjunction with source control to determine if a build was needed.